# How to select specific rows and their specific columns in bash?

Tags: text-processing

For example
I have this data, I want to get output as

```
serNo:  ASDFAFDAFD3223
                         profileType": "Asset Tag: profileValue": "12341233
corrected ouput as serNo:  ASDFAFDAFD3223
                Asset Tag: 12341233
_______________________________________________________________________
{
                "assetTag": null,
                "category": "Switch",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "profileType": "Asset Tag",
                        "profileValue": "12341233"
                    }
                ],
                "customerIpn": "234-234324-234",
                "loc": "23",
                "mfgPartNo": "ADSF-32C-ASDF",
                "parentSn": "APLADFKJAOFHKNFDSOIH",
                "partNo": "JPR-ADF-32C-ASDF",
                "position": "23",
                "serNo": "ASDFAFDAFD3223",
                "skuNo": 4125056,
                "subLoc": "1",
                "usageType": null,
                "vendor": "ASDFADSF NETWORKS (U.S.) INC"
            }
```

I tried methods like

```
 grep -e Switch -A4 | awk -F":" '/"profileValue"/{print $2}'
 "12341233"
 "ASDFKHKSHDF980"
 "ASDFDSF8689087"
 "SADFASIYYI86"
 "KHDSFKAYUSF86"
 "87698234"
 "97823407"
```

but cannot get expected data as Serno and Asset Tag

Comment: You should avoid a full upcase title. I can seems like you want people to know that your question is more important than the others.

Comment: please [edit] your question and format it well. also your expected output is not clear. what is your input data? what s your input data format/structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to process a JSON file is to use `jq`.

Then piping your file through `jq  '.serNo'` gives you :

```
"ASDFAFDAFD3223"
```

And `jq  '.children[].profileValue'` gives you:

```
"12341233"
```

You have the `-r` flag to remove the `"`. The output of both commands can be processed easily by `sed` if you want to add a prefix.

Comment: +1, but *The best way to process a JSON file **in shell** is to use `jq`*.  Many other languages (eg perl, python, js, java, C, and more) have their own json processing libraries for working with json data using each language's native data structures.

Comment: Yes, **in a shell** indeed!